# "Update" all of the unsaved buffers at vim

Tags: save

Is there a counterpart for the `wall` command at vim. I currently have an event handler for focus lost, so as whenever i switch to another window, vim would automatically write all of the buffers without exception (I don't know if that's the most efficient way to preserve my file changes or not). However, I was wondering if there happens to be a "plain" equivalent of `wall` but with the update command writing only unsaved buffers .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`:h :bufdo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Abufdo):

```
:[range]bufdo[!] {cmd}  Execute {cmd} in each buffer in the buffer list or if
            [range] is given only for buffers for which their
            buffer number is in the [range]. It works like doing
            this: 
                :bfirst
                :{cmd}
                :bnext
                :{cmd}
                etc.
```

So you could use `:bufdo update` to run `:update` on all your buffers and only change the unsaved ones.

Comment: It turned out to be having a small caveat, as `bufdo` with `update` or even `write` command switch the current buffer to another one, and so i have keep reverting back to the buffer i was in. Is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: Sure you could use [`:h getpos()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getpos%28%29) before you run the command and then [`:h setpos()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#setpos%28%29) once you're done to go back where you were.

Comment: I've added the following function
`function! Update_bufferz()
 let current_pos = getpos('.')
 silent! bufdo update
 call setpos('.', current_pos)
endfunction
` then `autocmd FocusLost * call Update_bufferz()`
but the same behavior still persists

Comment: As i've been looking for the reason behind it for a while now, google finally landed me the right [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24726022/14135669) which is exactly what i was looking for for. Still, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of `:wall` states:

> Write all changed buffers.  Buffers without a file name cause an error message.  Buffers which are readonly are not written.

It does not state "write all buffers".

This can be verified using `stat`, which will list the times of last access and modification. Alternatively, turn on vim's verbose log, write it to a file (`vim -V20vimlog ...`) and examine it for the files vim has and has not written.

Therefore, I believe that OP can just use `:wall` for the stated purpose. Caveat: I have only looked at vim 8.2 as shipped with git for Windows.

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim SE. FYI, Vim 9.0 on Linux seems to work the same.

Comment: Given that `wall` default behaviors is the intended behavior, then that's indeed more straightforward. I assume all that `bufdo` along with `update` is just being more flexible!